# Addressing computed key for use with a conditional ( $gt )

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to use the mongodb pipeline to get all states with electric stations having more than 100 "EV Level2 EVSE Num" and list the state abbreviation and count of Level2 chargers.

A document contains one electric station, there are many documents per state and the collection stores stations for every state in the USA.

I've tried to operate on $_id.totlv2 and $totlv2 but I'm lost on this and haven't understood the documentation well enough to leverage $gt in a pipeline. How can I filter states out that have less than 100 "EV Level2 EVSE Num"?

Query:

```
        db.altfuel.aggregate(
        {$match:{"Groups With Access Code": "Public"}},
        {$group:{ _id: "$State", totl2:{$sum: "$EV Level2 EVSE Num"}},
        {$sort:{"totl2":-1}}})
```

Relavent document keys:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57aa01d7f551936b0cbe9d56"),
    "State" : "UT",
    "Plus4" : "",
    "Groups With Access Code" : "Public",
    "EV Level1 EVSE Num" : "",
    "EV Level2 EVSE Num" : 4,
    "EV DC Fast Count" : "",
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do another $match after your group stage, where your aggregation would look like this:

```
db.altfuel.aggregate(
    {$match:{"Groups With Access Code": "Public"}},
    {$group:{ _id: "$State", totl2:{$sum: "$EV Level2 EVSE Num"}}},
    {$match: {"totl2": {$gte: 100}}},
    {$sort:{"totl2":-1}})
```

It also seemed like you misplaced some curly braces, which I've included the correct way in my answer.